# SQL : select unmatching records from 2 tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, where-clause

I have 2 tables and I want to retrieve the rows from the first table where the id_apartment does not appear in the second table:

```
id | id_floor | id_apartment 
----+----------+--------------
  1 |        0 |          101
  2 |        1 |          101
  3 |        1 |          102
  4 |        1 |          103
  5 |        1 |          104
  6 |        2 |          201
  7 |        2 |          202
  8 |        2 |          203


table2.id | table2.guest | table2.apartment_id
----+---------------+--------------
  1 |         65652 |          101
  2 |         65653 |          101
  3 |         65654 |          101
  4 |         65655 |          101
  5 |         65659 |          102
  6 |         65656 |          201
  7 |         65660 |          202
  8 |         65661 |          202
  9 |         65662 |          202
 10 |         65663 |          203
```

expected output:

```
floor | number
-------+--------
     1 |    103
     1 |    104
```

I tried using LEFT, INNER and RIGHT join but I always get EMPTY results. How can I manage this?

Comment: And where is `apartment_id = 1` in the second table?

Comment: How can `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN` gave you empty result???  Unless you have a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Also how do you think people can help fix your query if you don't post it?

Comment: I used WHERE table2.apartment_id = NULL

Comment: You need  to research NULL some. The statement x=Null never returns true even if x is null returns true.  X operand NULL (except for distinct from(?)) always returns NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick solution would be to use `not in`

```
Select * from table_1 where table_1.id_apartment not in (select apartment_id from table_2)
```

Comment: This might introduce performance overhead in comparison to `exists`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select *
from table1 t1
where not exists(
    select 1
    from table2 t2
    where t1.id_apartment = t2.apartment_id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The canonical solution is `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.apartment_id = t1.id_apatment);
```

However, that would also return the value of `1` in the first table as well as `103` and `104`.

I don't know if you want additional filtering on the `floor`, or if the data is just wrong in the question.

Comment: yes data was wrong it is 101 not 1. correct solution thanks easy understanding

Answer (score 0):

You could use a left anti-join here:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id_apartment = t2.apartment_id
WHERE
    t2.apartment_id IS NULL;
```

But exists logic should work just as well, and would actually be closer to a literal translation of your requirement.

Comment: I did this and it returned me an empty result.

Comment: Then maybe the problem is with your data, or how you phrased the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first tables' name is ***table1*** and second ones' name is ***table2***.

The answer of your question is:

```
select * from table1 t1 
where t1.id_apartment <> all (select t2.apartment_id from table2 t2 )
```